# Install MySQL on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: mysql, installation, ubuntu

This is my first time using Linux. I am trying to install MySQL 5.6.15 on an Ubuntu box. I download MySQL from their website and put it on a USB stick then plugged the stick into the box.

How can I install it using the downloaded package and not the built in package?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/linux-installation-debian.html

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to visit the [MySQL download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql).
2. Select your preferred platform (I prefer Debian Linux). And then select your OS-type (32-bit or 64-bit).
3. Click on the Download button. It will ask if you want to Sign Up or Login, just choose the **No thanks, just start my download**. If you are downloading the `.deb` file on the terminal right click the link and choose Copy Link Address. Open the terminal, type wget (paste the link).
4. After downloading, you can double click on the `.deb` file or type in your terminal `sudo dpkg -i (filename)`

You are done. I usually have trouble installing the 5.6 version, if so visit [this site](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/mysql-5-6-ubuntu-12-04).

Answer (score 0):

Download TAR package from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

and follow the procedure mentioned here 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-installation.html